# Lottery based counting problem based on uniqueness and monotonicity

Tags: combinatorics

I was solving [this problem](http://topcoder.bgcoder.com/print.php?id=268) and have prepared a solution [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78443/finding-lottery-odds-topcoder-268).

---

Problem summary:

Consider choosing `Blank` number of integers from 1 to `Choices` with the conditions:

- If `Sorted` is true then the numbers must be chosen in nondescending order
- If `Unique` is true then the numbers are chosen without replacement

For example, if ${\rm Choices} = 15$ , ${\rm Blanks} = 4$, ${\rm Sorted} = {\rm False}$, and ${\rm Unique} = {\rm true}$, then $\{3,~ 7,~ 12,~ 14\}$ would be a valid choice.

I am asked to find how many valid choices there are, given the 4 conditions.

---

4 Examples are given, I have having trouble with the 2nd one.

$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c}
\text{Example Name} & \text{Choices} & \text{Blanks} & \text{Sorted} & \text{Unique} \\ \hline
\text{Pick Any Two}       & 10 & 2 & F & F \\ \hline
\text{Pick Two In Order}  & 10 & 2 & T & F \\ \hline
\text{Pick Two Different} & 10 & 2 & F & T \\ \hline
\text{Pick Two Limited}   & 10 & 2 & T & T \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

The solution to the examples, the number of valid choices, is given as:

$$\begin{array} {cccccc} \hline
\text{Pick Any Two}       & 100 &\text{ *i.e* }& 10 \times 10 \\ \hline
\text{Pick Two In Order}  & 55 \\ \hline
\text{Pick Two Different} & 90 &\text{ *i.e.* }& 10 \times 9 &\text{ *i.e.* }& \frac{10!}{(10-2)!} \\ \hline
\text{Pick Two Limited}   & 45 &\text{ *i.e.* }& {10 \choose 2} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

---

I am having problems understanding the `PICK TWO IN ORDER` part.

How is it defined? Is it `PICK ANY TWO minus PICK TWO LIMITED`

because that is how I have implemented it, but it gives one of the answers wrong.

Comment: Please look at my edit (you can use the edit button) to see how to format a post for this website using Latex, and how to present information in a terser readable way.

Comment: @DanielV Thank you! - Humanity. I don't know Latex, hence tried to work with whatever markdown I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$% Predefined Typography
 \newcommand{\paren} [1]{\left({#1}\right)}
 \newcommand{\bparen}[1]{\bigg({#1}\bigg)}
 \newcommand{\brace} [1]{\left\{{#1}\right\}}
 \newcommand{\bbrace}[1]{\bigg\{{#1}\bigg\}}
 \newcommand{\floor} [1]{\left\lfloor{#1}\right\rfloor}
 \newcommand{\bfloor}[1]{\bigg\lfloor{#1}\bigg\rfloor}
 \newcommand{\mag}  [1]{\left\lVert{#1}\right\rVert}
 \newcommand{\bmag} [1]{\bigg\Vert{#1}\bigg\Vert}
 \newcommand{\abs}  [1]{\left\vert{#1}\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\babs} [1]{\bigg\vert{#1}\bigg\vert}
 %
 \newcommand{\labelt}[2]{\underbrace{#1}_{\text{#2}}}
 \newcommand{\label} [2]{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}
 %
 \newcommand{\setcomp}[2]{\left\{~{#1}~~\middle \vert~~ {#2}~\right\}}
 \newcommand{\bsetcomp}[2]{\bigg\{~{#1}~~\bigg \vert~~ {#2}~\bigg\}}
 %
 \newcommand{\iint}[2]{\int {#1}~{\rm d}{#2}}
 \newcommand{\dint}[4]{\int_{#3}^{#4}{#1}~{\rm d}{#2}}
 \newcommand{\pred}[2]{\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}{#2}}#1}
 \newcommand{\ind} [2]{\frac{{\rm d} {#1}}{{\rm d}{#2}}}
 \newcommand{\predp}[2]{\frac{\partial}{\partial {#2}}#1}
 \newcommand{\indp} [2]{\frac{{\partial} {#1}}{\partial {#2}}}
 \newcommand{\predn}[3]{\frac{\rm d}^{#3}{{\rm d}{#2}^{#3}}#1}
 \newcommand{\indn} [3]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#3} {#1}}{{\rm d}{#2}^{#3}}}
 %
 \newcommand{\ii}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\ee}{{\rm e}}
 \newcommand{\exp}[1] { {\rm e}^{\large{#1}} }
 %
 \newcommand{\and} {~\text{and}~}
 \newcommand{\or} {~\text{or}~}
%
 \newcommand{\red}  [1]{\color{red}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\blue} [1]{\color{blue}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\green}[1]{\color{green}{#1}}
$

The "Pick Two in Order" choice is:

- Pick 2 values
- From 1 to 10 Inclusive
- With the first value less than the second value
- Duplication is not excluded

So you are asking for the size of the set :

$$\setcomp{(x, y)}{1 \le x \le 10 \and 1 \le y \le 10 \and x \le y}$$

Or the red values from the table:

$$\begin{array} {cccccccccc}
\red{(1,~ 1)} & (2,~ 1) & (3,~ 1) & (4,~ 1) & (5,~ 1) & (6,~ 1) & (7,~ 1) & (8,~
 1) & (9,~ 1) & (10,~ 1) & \\
\red{(1,~ 2)} & \red{(2,~ 2)} & (3,~ 2) & (4,~ 2) & (5,~ 2) & (6,~ 2) & (7,~ 2)
& (8,~ 2) & (9,~ 2) & (10,~ 2) & \\
\red{(1,~ 3)} & \red{(2,~ 3)} & \red{(3,~ 3)} & (4,~ 3) & (5,~ 3) & (6,~ 3) & (7
,~ 3) & (8,~ 3) & (9,~ 3) & (10,~ 3) & \\
\red{(1,~ 4)} & \red{(2,~ 4)} & \red{(3,~ 4)} & \red{(4,~ 4)} & (5,~ 4) & (6,~ 4
) & (7,~ 4) & (8,~ 4) & (9,~ 4) & (10,~ 4) & \\
\red{(1,~ 5)} & \red{(2,~ 5)} & \red{(3,~ 5)} & \red{(4,~ 5)} & \red{(5,~ 5)} &
(6,~ 5) & (7,~ 5) & (8,~ 5) & (9,~ 5) & (10,~ 5) & \\
\red{(1,~ 6)} & \red{(2,~ 6)} & \red{(3,~ 6)} & \red{(4,~ 6)} & \red{(5,~ 6)} &
\red{(6,~ 6)} & (7,~ 6) & (8,~ 6) & (9,~ 6) & (10,~ 6) & \\
\red{(1,~ 7)} & \red{(2,~ 7)} & \red{(3,~ 7)} & \red{(4,~ 7)} & \red{(5,~ 7)} &
\red{(6,~ 7)} & \red{(7,~ 7)} & (8,~ 7) & (9,~ 7) & (10,~ 7) & \\
\red{(1,~ 8)} & \red{(2,~ 8)} & \red{(3,~ 8)} & \red{(4,~ 8)} & \red{(5,~ 8)} &
\red{(6,~ 8)} & \red{(7,~ 8)} & \red{(8,~ 8)} & (9,~ 8) & (10,~ 8) & \\
\red{(1,~ 9)} & \red{(2,~ 9)} & \red{(3,~ 9)} & \red{(4,~ 9)} & \red{(5,~ 9)} &
\red{(6,~ 9)} & \red{(7,~ 9)} & \red{(8,~ 9)} & \red{(9,~ 9)} & (10,~ 9) & \\
\red{(1,~ 10)} & \red{(2,~ 10)} & \red{(3,~ 10)} & \red{(4,~ 10)} & \red{(5,~ 10
)} & \red{(6,~ 10)} & \red{(7,~ 10)} & \red{(8,~ 10)} & \red{(9,~ 10)} & \red{(1
0,~ 10)} & \\
\end{array}$$

of which there are 55.

Comment: Nice explanation! I have a condition `<Choices, Blanks, Sorted, False>: <93 8 T F>`. Now for this condition, I can't use the above method.

Comment: @yadav_vi Indeed, I was only trying to get you to understand where the 55 came from so that you would understand the question.  Understanding the question is the first step.  Now see Joffan's answer, specifically "stars and bars" , for how to solve the problem.

Comment: What confuses me (in this case) is `PICK ANY TWO` **minus** `PICK TWO LIMITED` also yields the same result. Is it just a coincidence? or is there something more to it?

Comment: @yadav_vi the easiest way to program this case is probably just to observe that $$f(c, b) = \sum_{k=1}^c f(k, b-1)$$ and use memoization (sometimes abhorrently called "dynamic programming") to compute $f$

Comment: Will do. And I love "dynamic programming".

Answer (score 0):

Your SORTED + not UNIQUE option is combinations with repetition. It can be calculated from a "stars & bars" approach, with the CHOICES as categories. The $b$ BLANKS are then assigned to the $c$ CHOICES with the following number of combinations:  $${b+c-1\choose b} = \frac{(b+c-1)!}{b!(c-1)!}$$

The calculation you propose works only for 2 BLANKS.